# How to get certain values from user input and ignore others

Tags: c++, input, iostream

Is there any way of getting only the numbers from this string input:

```
h8 f7
```

If tried fscanf. But, probably i'm using it wrong.

```
int positionOfTheKnight = 0, finalDestination = 0;

fscanf("%*s%d %*s%d", &positionOfTheKnight, &finalDestination);

cout << positionOfTheKnight << " " << finalDestination;
```

It shows this following error:

```
cpp|11|error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'FILE* {aka _iobuf*}' for argument '1' to 'int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)'|
```

Comment: Compiler error message is correct.  `fscanf()` first argument is wrong, it should of `FILE*` type.

Comment: I really appreciate your words. Though, is there any way of getting my desired input? with or without the help of fscanf? I am a beginner in c++, I beg your pardon.

Comment: If you want to use [`fscanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) with standard input channel your first argument had to be `stdin`. Alternatively, you could use `scanf()` which reads from standard input. Btw. it's tagged [tag:c++]: Why not [`iostream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io)?

Comment: Scheff, I've updated the tag. Can you please give me an example about how to take those inputs with the help of scanf?

Comment: If you want to address the comment of somebody, please, prefix with `@`. That produces a notification of that person.

Comment: That's a marvelous help you've done @Scheff, it'd really help me in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a small sample to demonstrate multiple ways to read the example of OP:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int rcToInt(char c, char r)
{
  if (c < 'a' || c > 'h' || r < '1' || r > '8') {
    std::cerr << "Wrong input!\n";
    return -1;
  }
  return (c - 'a') * 8 + (r - '1'); // convert characters to index
}

int main()
{
  { // using scanf
    std::cout << "Using scanf():\n";
    char r0, c0, r1, c1;
    if (scanf(" %c%c %c%c ", &c0, &r0, &c1, &r1) < 4) {
      std::cerr << "Reading move with scanf() failed!\n";
    } else {
      const int pos0 = rcToInt(c0, r0), pos1 = rcToInt(c1, r1);
      if (pos0 >= 0 && pos1 >= 0) {
        std::cout << "Got " << c0 << r0 << " -> " << c1 << r1 << '\n';
      }
    }
  }
  { // Yet another way to use scanf():
    std::cout << "Using scanf():\n";
    char c0[2], r0[2], c1[2], r1[2];
    if (scanf("%1[a-h]%1[1-8] %1[a-h]%1[1-8] ", c0, r0, c1, r1) < 4) {
      std::cerr << "Reading move with scanf() failed!\n";
    } else {
      const int pos0 = rcToInt(*c0, *r0), pos1 = rcToInt(*c1, *r1);
      if (pos0 >= 0 && pos1 >= 0) {
        std::cout << "Got " << c0 << r0 << " -> " << c1 << r1 << '\n';
      }
    }
  }
  { // using std::cin
    std::cout << "Using operator>>():\n";
    char r0, c0, r1, c1;
    if (!(std::cin >> c0 >> r0 >> c1 >> r1)) {
      std::cerr << "Reading move with operator>>() failed!\n";
    } else {
      const int pos0 = rcToInt(c0, r0), pos1 = rcToInt(c1, r1);
      if (pos0 >= 0 && pos1 >= 0) {
        std::cout << "Got " << c0 << r0 << " -> " << c1 << r1 << '\n';
      }
    }
  }
  // There is still the [ENTER] in input queue which must be consumed:
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  // ...before proceeding
  { // using std::cin
    std::cout << "Using std::getline():\n";
    std::string line;
    if (!std::getline(std::cin, line) || line.size() < 5) {
      std::cerr << "Reading move with std::getline() failed!\n";
    } else {
      const char c0 = line[0], r0 = line[1], c1 = line[3], r1 = line[4];
      const int pos0 = rcToInt(c0, r0), pos1 = rcToInt(c1, r1);
      if (pos0 >= 0 && pos1 >= 0) {
        std::cout << "Got " << c0 << r0 << " -> " << c1 << r1 << '\n';
      }
    }
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Using scanf():
h8 f7↵
Got h8 -> f7
Using scanf():
f7 h8↵
Got f7 -> h8
Using operator>>():
h8 f7↵
Got h8 -> f7
Using std::getline():
f7 h8↵
Got f7 -> h8
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e639e1892c9aee5)</kbd>

All four alternatives follow the basic idea to read the input as characters and convert them to a corresponding index in the range of [0, 63] afterwards.

While `char` might represent characters, it's as well an integral value – specifically the smallest available integral type. In (C and) C++, this is no difference. A character `'1'` is stored as integer value `33` (assuming [ASCII](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange) code)). `'1'` as well as `33` represent the same value. Hence, it is fine (and even recommended) to use character constants for arithmetic computations if appropriate (like in `rcToInt()` in the above example).

1. `if (scanf(" %c%c %c%c ", &c0, &r0, &c1, &r1) < 4) {`

   - Formatter starts with a space () to consume optionally pending white space.
   - `%c` stores one character. Hence, a `char*` argument (pointing to sufficient storage) has to be provided.
   - Formatter ends with a space () to consume the terminating <kbd>ENTER</kbd> as well.
   - The return value of `scanf()` is checked to grant that all 4 arguments will be assigned.
2. `if (scanf(" %1[a-h]%1[1-8] %1[a-h]%1[1-8] ", c0, r0, c1, r1) < 4) {`

   - Formatter starts and ends with a space () to consume surrounding white space (like in the previous example).
   - `%1[a-h]` reads a string of length 1 which may consist of characters `a`, `b`, ..., `h` only. There has to be provided storage for an extra byte as that formatter will always store an additional 0-terminator (`\0`). Hence, the declations `char c0[2], r0[2], c1[2], r1[2];` in this case.
   - `%1[1-8]` similar like above for the characters `1`, `2`, ..., `8`. Please note, that digits are read as characters.
3. `if (!(std::cin >> c0 >> r0 >> c1 >> r1)) {`

   - Read four `char` variables using stream input operators.
     The `iostream` header provides a variety of overloaded `operator>>`s (e.g. `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, char&)`) for this.
   - The whitespace (occurring before reading `c1`) is skipped by default setting of `std::cin`.
4. `if (!std::getline(std::cin, line) || line.size() < 5) {`

   - Read a whole line into a `std::string` (which is grown appropriately).
   - Analyze characters in that `std::string`.

A combination of 3. and 4. would be to read a line with `std::getline()`, wrap the read line in a `std::istringstream` to parse it with input stream operators.

---

Sorry, if I swapped row and column in the above code. I'm no chess expert and not aware of the usual convertions.